# Inconsistent behavior of lines and words

Tags: haskell

Here is a GHCi session:

```
Prelude> words " one two three"
["one","two","three"]
Prelude> lines "\none\ntwo\nthree"
["","one","two","three"]
```

Is there a reason for this inconsistency? And, if so, what is it?

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty word. There *is* such a thing as an empty line.

Comment: A blank line is still a line, but the empty string is not a word. I know that's a bit glib, but I think it captures the reasoning pretty concisely.

Comment: Whether there is an empty word depends on the definition of word, but I do understand, though, that it would be misleading to say " one two three" has 4 words. OTOH, sometimes it is interesting to know whether the string actually starts with a word.

Comment: Note that this isn't unique to Haskell. E.g. in python: `' one two three'.split() --> ['one', 'two', 'three']` and `'\none\ntwo\nthree'.splitlines() --> ['', 'one', 'two', 'three']`  which is exactly the same behaviour, for the exact same reasons.

Answer (score 9):

`lines` is an actual bijection: you can use it to split up any string at the `'\n'` characters, and later reassemble them perfectly with `unlines`. (Well, almost: let's disregard trailing newlines and Windows line ending.)

If `words` had the same behaviour just with `' '` instead of `'\n'` as the separator character, it wouldn't quite work the way we want it: for instance, the string

```
     "I will not buy this record\nit is scratched"
```

would get split up to

```
     ["I","will","not","buy","this","record\nit","is","scratched"]
```

which `words` avoids, by splitting at *any* whitespace.

```
Prelude> words "I will not buy this record\nit is scratched"
["I","will","not","buy","this","record","it","is","scratched"]
```

This means that **a)** it's not a bijection anyway, because the flavour of whitespace is lost, and **b)** you would get a lot of “empty words” when there are any two whitespace characters adjacent.

Hence, the sensible behaviour for `words` is to just condense such whitespace into a single gap.